# Delta row compression in PCLXL

Tags: printing, compression, pclxl, delta-row-compression

Is there a difference in the implementation of delta row compression between PCLXL and PCL5?

I was using Delta Row compression in PCL5, but when I used the same method in PCLXL, the file is not valid. I checked the output using EscapeE and it says that the image data size is incorrect..

Could anyone point me to some material explaining how delta row compression is implemented in PCLXL?

Thanks,

kreb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I found this and it is indeed different..

from http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1577259&page=1 user guptadeepak03

> Actually I did some research on that too. I found it hard way that there are few differences in the way the formats are in PCL-XL and PCL-5. To quote from the reference manual provided by HP(PCL-XL ver 2.1):
>
> The PCL XL implementation follows the
>   PCL5 implementation except in the
>   following:
>
> 1) the seed row is
>   initialized to zeroes and contains the
>   number of bytes defined by SourceWidth
>   in the BeginImage operator.
>
> 2) the delta row is preceded by a 2-byte byte
>   count which indicates the number of
>   bytes to follow for the delta row. The
>   byte count is expected to be in LSB
>   MSB order.
>
> 3) to repeat the last row, use the 2-byte byte count of 00 00.

Will mark this answered as soon as I can.. Thanks..